# Junk mail filter for iPhone via imap

Tags: iphone, mail.app, email, sleep-wake, imap

I have:

- Mac Book Pro running OS X 10.10.2
- iPhone 6 Plus running iOS 8.1.3

On my computer I run Mail, which checks the email every 1 min.  On my iPhone it runs every 15 mins.  So most of the time, my computer receives the email first and filters the message so my phone never gets the junk mail.  However when my computer is sleeping my iphone normally gets the email first and does not perform the filter for the junk mail.

Options:

1. Force the computer not to sleep
2. Write a script to run while sleeping asking mail query the server (I'm not sure how hard this would be)
3. Ask here and see if someone has a better idea.

Comment: 1) would work… 2) would wake the puter every minute, in effect. 3) I'd like to see an answer too, tbh, though I don't have IMAP, so I get it all anyway - Apple claims there's already a junk filter, but I'm guessing it's iCloud only - https://support.apple.com/en-sa/HT202315

Answer (score 3):

The best idea is to pay for (or set up) server side junk mail filtering. That allows all the clients to only spend time downloading non-junk.

Have a look at Mail Route (10 percent off link from the podcast where I heard about it sponsoring most recently) - http://mailroute.net/thetalkshow.html

You probably will spend more on the service than the cost to run your Mac all the time, but the filters will likely be much better on the hosted site than OS X mail client.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, the only thing I can really think of is setting up stricter filtering rules with your host, be that iCloud or Gmail or whathaveyou. You can weirdly only do this for iCloud using their webmail interface. You might also try using SpamSieve on your OS X inbox to train mail to sort items as Good or Junk; I believe those designations once determined are maintained for the iOS clients, but it takes a while to get it trained. I'd love a better mobile spam solution & hope someone else provides a better answer.

Comment: Unfortunately my host does not have a good system.  From my search spam filtering seems to be a problem on iPhone.  Thanks